# Feminizing Biblical names?

Tags: minhag, names

Masculine names such as Daniel, Joseph, and Michael have feminized forms: Danielle/Daniela, Josephine/Josephina, Michelle/Michaela/Mikayla.

I've heard that when choosing a name for a baby, you would look up a particular Torah portion, depending on the baby's birthday.

But, on a more *general note*, what is the commonality of religious Jews feminizing masculine Biblical names if they have a baby girl? Obviously there is no prohibition against this (that I know of), but I have never heard of religious Jews feminizing common Biblical names which are originally masculine, although this is common among Christians: Josephine (Joseph) and Joanna (John). Do Jews ever do this?

Maybe it's just me, but I've never heard of there being a Josephina among religious Jews.
Why don't religious Jews ever feminize names?

Even if the Biblical character is male, you're naming the child after their characteristics, values, morals, etc,...

Comment: Related: http://mi.yodeya.com/q/17297

Comment: You are mistaken: (even religious) Jews do this all the time. Is that really the extent of the question?

Answer (score 3):

The question is:

> on a more general note, what is the commonality of religious Jews feminizing masculine Biblical names if they have a baby girl? Obviously there is no prohibition against this (that I know of), but I have never heard of religious Jews feminizing common Biblical names which are originally masculine, although this is common among Christians: Josephine (Joseph) and Joanna (John). Do Jews ever do this?

And, assuming they don't:

> Why don't religious Jews ever feminize names?

Well, they do. I know a *Yaakova* and a *Davida*, and there are also people named *Yosefa* and so on. (As [I've noted elsewhere](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/39095), though, I've never heard of a *Titzchak*, *Taakov*, *Mosha*, or *Emraham*.)

I can't speak to "commonality", as sought. I don't think anyone has ever (in modern times) gathered statistics of baby names among religious Jews.

Comment: My daughter is a "Davita".  I still consider a feminization of David, even if I chose to spell it with a "t".  In Hebrew, it keeps the two dalets and then looks more like David.

Comment: Note that Yaakova is itself a Biblical name. See Divrei HaYamim 1:4:36